# Amazon S3 access control + bandwidth

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm thinking about maybe using Amazon S3, but have a few questions:

- does it provide access control to limit GETs?
- does it provide "high-speed" transfer?

I'm looking to serve large files to a vast number of end users. Each end user need to authenticate himself to our service before getting the file. Is this something that Amazon S3 can do? (Ive seen no scripting features at S3). I've seen a lot of authentication stuff and access control stuff, but it only seems to pertain to developers authenticating themselves, not the end user doing GETs. I'm hoping/thinking Amazon S3 would be a fast alternative (when talking bandwidth troughput) than just serving files through EC2, which turned out to be completely unsatisfying.

Comment: I have seen S3 being referred to having "high bandwidth" here: http://serverfault.com/questions/201810/benefits-of-amazon-s3/201818#201818 Now, "high bandwidth" is relative, and I'd like to somehow figure out just how high that is.

Comment: I'm currently finding Amazon CloudFront. Its features looks like what I'm looking for. http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"high-speed" transfer =>  CloudFront

Access control => not via S3, but you can use "long" URLs as workaround, such as http://aws.../uzuz967678678ghhhj/yourfile.pdf

Comment: Ok I'm gonna set this correct, partly biased because we're already with our feet in the EC2 water here, and I already found out about CloudFront. :-P I'm nervous with implementing the private content access however.